# How to unit test legacy J2EE application

Tags: java, unit-testing, scala, jakarta-ee

This may sound like a vague question but I am looking for some specif pointers.

Our J2EE app is built on `Struts2 + Plain Servlets + JSP + iBatis + Oracle`

I would prefer to write unit tests in Scala so that I can learn the language on the side as well

- What would I need to be able to verify that a spcific column is displayed in the JSP following some specific steps

  - Click on a link. select some parameters and submit the page to the servlet
  - Verify that the next page has a specific column inside its `<table>` tag.
- What would I need to create mock requests for the serlvet?

I am trying to write tests like above in addition to core business functionality tests however, the problem is that I am trying to wrap legacy code in unit tests and the code of course is not designed for unit testing.

Comment: Your example is far beyond unit testing.

Comment: True. the first step is not really unit testing, however, are there solutions out there that do test for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't call this unit testing. As you are trying to test integration of several units. Also it's rather hard to create a unit test for a JSP becuase it has many context dependencies available only when you are in the container.

Instead I would advice writing some automated functional tests that are executed against running (deployed) application.

Frameworks like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) may be of great help here as they allow to simulate real user behaviour and make asserts against produced HTML code.

**EDIT**: Another approach here may be to:

- start an embedded servlet container like [Jetty](http://www.christianschenk.org/blog/testing-web-applications-with-jetty/) within your test code
- deploy all your plain servlets and JSPs to that
- replace Oracle database with in-memory database like [HSQL](http://hsqldb.org/) or [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/)
- populate it with some test data using [DBUnit](http://www.dbunit.org/)
- and then again use either [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) (which has Java binding) or [HttpUnit](http://httpunit.sourceforge.net/) to make requests and asserts against generated HTML code.

But again it will not be a unit test, but rather an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

Like everyone said, your not really talking about unit testing. You're talking about functional testing. I'd think hard about what your real goals are. What is driving this push for automated testing? Does the application have configuration issues(i.e. its hard to configure so some parts work and others don't). This might justify building a smoke test suite in selenium targeting your pain pages and test cases. This will also help detect regression bugs.

As for the legacy concerns. No application is beyond help. If you are running front end tests in selenium then it doesn't matter how the code is written as long as its parseable HTML.

As for your actual server side code. You just gotta roll [Andy Dufresne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Dufresne) style. As you fix bugs and add functionality code with Test Driven Development principles in mind. Rework code that relates to your changes and add unit tests. You'd be surprised at how fast a legacy app can come around if you keep chipping away at it.